# How to map Json to Java object using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using jackson to map json which I get from my post rest api to map to a java object.

the json is represent by

```
{
  "baseName": "xyz",
  "salary": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "info": {
        "ename": "john",
        "eid": 143
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "info": {
        "ename": "bg",
        "eid": 123
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The java class are represent by

BaseInfo.java

```
class BaseInfo {
     String baseName;
     ArrayList<salary> salaries = new ArrayList<salary>();
}
```

Salary.java

```
class Salary {
    int id;
    EmplInfo emp;
}
```

EmplInfo.java

```
class EmplInfo{
    String ename;
    int eid;
}
```

But in the when call the api with this json I get the arraylist initialized but contains nothings. What I am doing wrong ? I get other information like baseName,etc

Comment: have you had a look onto gson already? There's a bunch of methods to solve that kind of problem without having to reinvent the wheel :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `JsonProperty` annotation to [rename properties](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#annotations-for-renaming-properties)

```
class BaseInfo {
    String baseName;
    @JsonProperty("salary")
    ArrayList<salary> salaries = new ArrayList<salary>();
}

class Salary {
    int id;
    @JsonProperty("info")
    EmplInfo emp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are the solutions:

Either add JsonProperty annotations as specified by Michael or update json keys i.e 'salary' to 'salaries' and 'info' to 'emp'